# working with url encoding in requesthandler in webapp2

Tags: python-2.7, webapp2

This is the code I tried so far.

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

class Data(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, url):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(url)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', MainPage),
    (r'/data/(.*$)', Data),
], debug=True)
```

if i open this url in chrome:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/data/https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JAYsWerYJ8b08weOpqqAAQ&gws_rd=ssl` ;

I get `https:/www.google.co.in/`
instead of:
`https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JAYsWerYJ8b08weOpqqAAQ&gws_rd=ssl`

I know that this must be obvious but I could not locate how to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you encode and decode the url then I would suggest something like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/data/https:%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F%3Fgfe_rd=cr&ei=JAYsWerYJ8b08weOpqqAAQ&gws_rd=ssl` than will print the full url if you encode it like that.

```
import urllib

class Data(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, url):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(urllib.unquote(url))
```

Using the encoded url and then unquoting with urrllib seems to solve the problem, if you can.